# PHP cURL working locally, error 77 on AWS server

Tags: php, curl, nginx, amazon-ec2, parse-platform

**LATEST UPDATE:** script is running successfully via SSH shell as "php script.php", being an admin user. When run by the nginx user, the curl command fails to do the https request. So I guess it's an issue of nginx user not being able to use curl properly. I've checked tenths of configuration files and cannot find where this could be changed.

I'm trying to post the following JSON

```
{
    "where": {
      "userId": "97"
    },
    "data": {
      "alert": "Joe Masilotti answered a question you follow",
      "badge": "Increment","eventId":"3","questionId":"8954","answerId":"977"
    }
}
```

with the following code

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'parse.com-php-library/2.0');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: '.$this->_appid,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: '.$this->_restkey
)); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

$postData = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'',$args['data']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData );
$url = $this->_parseurl . $args['requestUrl'];
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($c);
```

It works on my local Apache. I run this on an nginx server running on AWS EC2 and getting this from cURL

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.parse.com/1/push
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.012399
    [namelookup_time] => 0.01232
    [connect_time] => 0.013486
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)


cURL error number:77

cURL error:
```

The same JSON is sent OK from the command line of the AWS EC2 server with the following command

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <...>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:<..>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "userId": "97"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Joe answered a question",
          "badge": "Increment","eventId":"3","questionId":"8954","answerId":"977"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

cURL extension is set up properly on the server, and it works in other scripts. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** The script "script.php" runs successfully when run on server from command line as "php script.php", while failing when requested on a browser at "http://www.mysite.com/script.php"

**UPDATE:** Here's my curl -V

```
curl 7.36.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.36.0 NSS/3.16 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

and I was trying to check curl differences between my local and server PHP configs, I saw that local curl SSL version is **OpenSSL/1.0.1f** while on server is **NSS/3.14.3.0**

Comment: You have an issue with the SSL certificate. CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE (77)

Comment: I have the curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); so that's not the issue, plus it runs OK if I post it with curl from the command line

Comment: What does `ini_get('curl.cainfo')` say in both environments?

Comment: In both cases it gives null (returning nothing). I'm now seeing that curl is built with NSS, and certutil tells me that "function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format."

Comment: ofcourse if it was a certificate problem, I wouldn't be able to https post at all. Script runs from command line, but not when nginx runs it

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error on amazon AMI linux.

I Solved by setting **curl.cainfo** on **/etc/php.d/curl.ini**

check my **curl.ini**
https://gist.github.com/reinaldomendes/97fb2ce8a606ec813c4b

Comment: On Ubuntu the correct path was /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question after 2 days of debugging. After playing with compiling everything one by one, I realized that after the last update in the Amazon Linux server - caused by the heartbleed issue, there was a problem with NSS, package manager couldn't update it because of some broken dependencies.

The one solution was to re-compile PHP with cURL using openSSL instead of NSS. Before doing that and spend hours (as also not relying on the ease of package management), I created a fresh Amazon Linux server to check if they had updated the package management and NSS worked in the new AMIs. And they had. Popped a new instance, did a yum update before anything else, and NSS was the first to be updated.

Tried the above code and worked. So, now I'm moving all the codebase to the new instance, switching EIP to the new instance and all good.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence in solving the issue, it saved me a lot of time.  I had the same issue with one of my AWS boxes (also since Heartbleed patching).  In my case, I was able to `yum update` and grab the latest NSS and openssl packages.  Then I stopped and started Apache and everything was fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JimOHalloran Restarting the httpd worked for me. the problem had seeped in after a yum update.

Answer (score 2):

Ends up, stopping and starting Apache was required for me.

I couldn't believe it myself. On my AWS EC2, I had yum updated everything and still it wasn't working. This was trying to cUrl post to authorize.net. Ends up, get this, thanks to @JimOHalloran restart wasn't doing it.

- apachectl graceful (no)
- apachectl restart (no)
- apachectl stop
- apachectl start

BAM! Problem fixed - I spent 3+ hours today banging my head and reading every page online about this problem. I have NO CLUE what that's different than a hard restart but it did. Apparently something else (Curl? OpenSSL?) got restarted too then.

Comment: This also solved it for me. I had also updated my curl.ini as explained in Reinaldo Mendes's answer, so it's possible both of those steps were necessary.

Comment: “Sometimes the easiest solution, is the last thing on your mind”

Answer (score 2):

Jsut restart the php-fpm,everything is ok.

```
eg: sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the post and I instructed the vps managed provider to restart the Apache and php-fpm and it magically worked!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon servers do this often when they are running out of memory. Check your server's RAM consumption and bump it up these errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on an EC2 instance in PHP code that had been working happily for over a year and found I had to:

1. download the latest `cacert.pem` from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. restart Apache (`sudo service httpd restart`)

I'm setting the path in my PHP so didn't need to change `php.ini` or `curl.ini`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');
```

Comment: Tried this one didn’t work for me but simply restart the Apache and php works

Answer (score 0):

This problem took me 1 day.

The solution:

> Note: If you have a hosting, you should contact your hosting provider

> These commands are for Centos 7

run this commands

```
# update ca-certificates
sudo yum install -y ca-certificates

# open php.ini 
sudo vi /etc/php.ini
```

Change these

```
curl.cainfo = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

openssl.cafile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

run this commands

```
# reload httpd
sudo systemctl reload httpd

# reload nginx
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Please don't start with 'The solution is simple' It might be the case for you, but someone with less knowledge might feel demoralized by it, and might be discoraged from asking another question. Also this question has been answered by the OP himself already 8 years ago (although not accepted as answer). An important part of your answer is missing as well, Why do we need to run those commands.