# Why does Amazon SES fail half the time when called using the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP (version 3.52.33, PHP version 7.2.19) and trying to send emails using the Simple Email Service (SES). I have SES configured, and can run the example code successfully. To make my life easier, I wrote a function to send emails (`send_email.php`):

```php
<?php

// Path to autoloader for AWS SDK
define('REQUIRED_FILE', "/path/to/vendor/autoload.php");

// Region:
define('REGION','us-west-2');

// Charset
define('CHARSET','UTF-8');

// Specify Sender
define('SENDER', 'sender@xxxx.com');

require REQUIRED_FILE;

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException;


function send_email($htmlBody,$textBody,$subject,$recipient) {

        $access_key = 'accessKey';
        $secret_key = 'secretKey';

        $ret_array = array('success' => false,
                        'message' => 'No Email Sent'
                        );

        $client = SesClient::factory(array(
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => REGION,
                'credentials' => array(
                        'key' => $access_key,
                        'secret' => $secret_key
                )
        ));


        try {
                $result = $client->sendEmail([
                        'Destination' => [
                                'ToAddresses' => [
                                        $recipient,
                                ],
                        ],
                        'Message' => [
                                'Body' => [
                                        'Html' => [
                                                'Charset' => CHARSET,
                                                'Data' => $htmlBody,
                                        ],
                                        'Text' => [
                                                'Charset' => CHARSET,
                                                'Data' => $textBody,
                                        ],
                                ],
                                'Subject' => [
                                        'Charset' => CHARSET,
                                        'Data' => $subject,
                                ],
                        ],
                        'Source' => SENDER,
                ]);

                $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
                $ret_array['success'] = true;
                $ret_array['message'] = $messageId;
                echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId" . "\n");
        } catch (SesException $error) {
                echo("The email was not sent. Error message: " . $error->getAwsErrorMessage() . "\n");
                $ret_array['message'] = $error->getAwsErrorMessage();
        }

        return $ret_array;
}
```

This works when called from a simple testing script (`test.php`) in a terminal:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require_once './send_email.php';

$email = 'test@email.com';
$htmlbody = 'test';
$txtbody = 'test';
$subject = 'test email';

$success = send_email($htmlbody,$txtbody,$subject,$email);
```

I get output like:

```
[~]$ php test.php
Email sent! Message ID: 0101016c8d665369-027be596-f8da-4410-8f09-ff8d7f87181b-000000
```

which is great. However, I'm doing this to send automated emails from a website (new user registration, password resets, ...) and when I try to use `send_email` from within a larger script I get a ~%50 success rate (when using a constant email address). Either it works and everything is fine, or it fails without an error message:

```
The email was not sent. Error message:
```

I know that an exception is being thrown, as I'm ending up in the `catch` statement, but I don't know how to get more information about what went wrong since there isn't a message associated with the exception. I've tried expanding what I look for in the `catch` block:

```php
<snip>
catch (SesException $error) {
                echo("The email was not sent. Error message: " . $error->getAwsErrorMessage() . "\n");
                $ret_array['message'] = $error->getAwsErrorMessage();
                $ret_array['errorCode'] = $error->getAwsErrorCode();
                $ret_array['type'] = $error->getAwsErrorType();
                $ret_array['response'] = $error->getResponse();
                $ret_array['statusCode'] = $error->getStatusCode();
                $ret_array['isConnectionError'] = $error->isConnectionError();
        }
```

but when it fails everything is `NULL` except `isConnectionError = false`. Anecdotally, it is totally random -- I haven't been able to discern a pattern at all as to when it works and when it fails.

One other potentially relevant note: if I loop the email sending so a new user gets 10 emails, either they **all** succeed or they **all** fail.

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going wrong, or other steps I could take to help diagnose why this is happening?

Comment: Could you be hitting the SES per second sending limit?

Comment: If so, you can throttle/sleep between sends

Comment: For testing I'm only sending one (or a few) at a time -- my limit on burst sending is something like 14/sec, so I doubt I'm getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running in to a similar issue in the future, I eventually came up with two solutions:

Initially, I gave up hope on the AWS SDK and switched to using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which avoided the issue (though I believe at the cost of a loss in performance).

The real issue (I'm fairly certain now) was a mismatch in the versions of PHP between my CLI and what the webserver was providing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434792/) question got me thinking about how that might be the issue. By updating the version of cURL and PHP that the webserver was using, I resolved the issue.